# Element that gets bigger on :active without moving surrounding elements

Tags: css, width, padding

I have a sentence composed of multiple `span` elements:

```
<span class="sentence">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>second</span>
    <span>third.</span>
</span>
```

When a `span` gets clicked (`:active`), I want it to have an increased font but without moving the elements around it horizontally.

#### Idle

[image]

#### Second word :active

[image]

I don't want any Javascript involved (to compute the `:active` width of the element, or some hack like this), only CSS. A solution would be to add right/left padding by default and suppress it when a word is `:active`, but it doesn't work for all word lengths: http://jsfiddle.net/Ampwt/1/

Any idea of how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: scale()`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ampwt/2/.

```
<span class="sentence">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>second</span>
    <span>third.</span>
</span>

<br />

<span class="sentence">
    <span>First</span>
    <span>very long word</span>
    <span>third.</span>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.sentence span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:1.5em;
    padding:0 1em;
}
.sentence span:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply width and height to your span. Please see sample css.

```
.sentence span {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:1.5em;
    width: 170px;
    height:30px;
}
.sentence span:active {
    font-size:2em;
}
```

Comment: A word's width depends on its length, so you can't set an absolute dimension in this case.